# Function definition and function type

Tags: c++

I have the following code which works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int (TMyFunc)(int);

TMyFunc* p;

int x(int y)
{
    return y*2;
}

int main()
{
    p = &x;
    cout << (*p)(5) << endl;
}
```

What I want to do is skip defining `x` and define `p` there straight. Something like

`TMyFunc p; p(y){return y*2;}`.

Is that possible? If so how do I do it? If not why?

EDIT:

After seeing the answers, I think I should clarify: I want the definition to be separate. i.e. function definition will be in a shared object. An application will acquire a function pointer to the function via `dlsym`. I do **not** want a function object. What I want is to know if I can define a function using its type which a header file common to both the shared object and the application will provide. I hope that came out right :).

EDIT2: For sbi :)

This resides in a header which is included in both the application and the shared object:

```
#define FNAME_GET_FACTORY       "GetFactory"
#define FNAME_GET_FUNCTION_IDS  "GetFunctionIDs"
#define FNAME_GET_PLUGIN_INFO   "GetPluginInfo"

typedef FunctionFactory* (*TpfGetFactory)();
typedef size_t (*TpfGetFunctionIDs)(int**);
typedef PluginInfo* (*TpfGetPluginInfo)();
```

In the application, something like this happens:

```
TpfGetFactory pF = (TpfGetFactory)dlsym(pHandle, FNAME_GET_FACTORY);
//Use pF for anything
```

Now, to do this, I have to define `GetFactory` as follows in the shared object:

```
extern "C" FunctionFactory* FNAME_GET_FACTORY(){//CODE}
```

Forgetting the `extern "C"` part for now, Can I define this function using the type `TpfGetFactory` which is already defined? (This is not a huge issue I know - but I am curious as to whether it is possible :) ). What I want is something like this in the shared object :

```
TpfGetFactory f;
f(){//Implementation}
```

EDIT3:

My try:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef int (TF)(int);

TF f;

f(int x)
{
    return x*2;
}

int main()
{
    x(3);
}

main.cpp:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of â€˜fâ€™ with no type
main.cpp: In function â€˜int main()â€™:
main.cpp:16: error: â€˜xâ€™ was not declared in this scope
```

Comment: Can you add some (pseudo)code describing how you want to use it? Your added description confuses me more than it clarifies anything.

Comment: Removed the C tag, as there's no iostream or namespace std in C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's possible in C++1x, the next C++ standard, generally expected next year (which would make it C++11, then). It allows this:

```
auto p = [](int y){return y*2;};
```

This relies on `auto` been given a new meaning ("automatically deduce the type of this variable from the expression that initializes it") and the new lambda functions (allowing to create functions on the fly).

Your compiler might actually already support this.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me, with the current C++03 Standard:

```
typedef int (TMyFunc)(int);

TMyFunc* p;

int test()
{
    struct LocalClass
    {
        static int functionLocal(int y)
        {
            return 2;
        };
    };

    LocalClass localClass;
    p = &(LocalClass::functionLocal);
}
```

But maybe it happens to be more complicated to write than what you wanted to simplify ;-),
however it works and you can define your functions in place, locally.

Here is some documentation about [local classes](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr062.htm)

Comment: As I hope I clarified above, I don't want to get a functor :).

Comment: @Nakiya It is **NOT a functor** it is a function pointer! there is no **operator()** defined here !? it IS a function pointer, using the fact that we can define local class in C++. So I can define a local static function, which is just like a plain C function !

Comment: Srry, my mistake. However, if you read my problem (EDIT2), you'd see that what I am actually asking is whether I can use a typedef of a function to define a function. :). I am not in anyway concerned with function pointers or functors here. Perhaps I made the problem too convoluted by adding all the details.

Comment: @nakiya, okay, but what is your question ? you wonder whether it works. As far as I know it works ? As long as a typedef defines a typename, you can use this typename in prototypes. Have you tried to compile. I think it should be ok.

Comment: @Stephane Rolland: Yes I did try to compile. Compiler threw errors at me :).

Comment: @nakiya, please copy-paste the compilation errors. They are often full of information !

Comment: @nakiya I ask you for the compilation errors because it should work. I am a typedef fanatic. It always ease the readability. As far as I am used to it, it should work.

Comment: @nakiya, yep but what you wrote this time is complete C++ nonsense.

Comment: :D. I know I have never seen it before. That is why I asked in the original question : "Is that possible? If so how do I do it? If not why?" :D

Comment: No your code is simply false, you call `x(3)`, whereas x is defined nowhere in your 3rd edit, thus it cannot compile, I think you don't read compilation reports. And why do you want to define f **twice** ? At the moment you write `int f(int y){return y*2;}` then `&f` is of type int(*)(int). That's all. No more information needed. ?!

Answer (score 0):

This will be possible in the next C++ standard, via lambdas. In the current standard, however, it is impossible to define one function inside another.

Answer (score 0):

Not directly in C++98.

For standard C++, that is C++98, check out e.g. the [Boost Lambda](http://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/doc/html/lambda.html#introduction) library. It lets you write expressions like

```
for_each(a.begin(), a.end(), std::cout << _1 << ' ');
```

C++0x adds direct support for lambda expressions.

Cheers & hth.,