# Copy function signature

Tags: c++

I wish to create many functions with the same parameters, for example:

```
const int add(const int a, const int b) {
    return (a + b);
}
decltype(add) subtract {
    return (a - b);
}
/* many more functions */
```

The purpose being that I am able to easily change the types of the parameters once to change all of the functions. I know that this is possible with macros as so:

```
#define INT_OPERATION(name) const int name (const int a, const int b)
INT_OPERATION(add) { return (a + b); }
INT_OPERATION(subtract) {return (a - b); }
```

However, I dislike the use of macros. Is there a safer way of doing this?

Comment: Why not use templates?

Comment: Not sure what's the motivation behind this need. Could `std::plus` and `std::minus`, `std::minus`, etc. serve your needs?

Comment: Seems like those are just for explanatory reasons to keep it simple.

Comment: Somewhat related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4022984/function-definition-and-function-type

Comment: @RSahu Yes, as kfsone said, these are simply for the sake of demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function **signature** cannot be `typedef`ed. Only a function's type. So it's valid to say :

```
typedef int INT_OPERATION(int a, int b);
```

and then forward declare a function having this type :

```
INT_OPERATION Add;
```

**but** when it comes to **defining** the function you'd have to specify arguments, so the follwing is **invalid**

```
INT_OPERATION Add { /* No can do */ }
```

(as soon as you place a set of `()` after `Add` you'll be declaring a function returning a plain function which is not valid C++)

### On generic types

The same procedure has similar limitations when using the tools for generic programming. You **can** declare the following typedef :

```
template<typename T>
using INT_OPERATION = const T(T const, T const);
```

And then use it for a function (forward) declaration

```
INT_OPERATION<int> add;

int main() {
    std::cout << add(1, 2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

but when it comes to defining it, you'd have to be mandane

```
const int add(int const a, int const b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/6dICTI)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function<int(int, int)> IntFunction;

IntFunction add = [](int a, int b) {return a + b;};
IntFunction substract = [](int a, int b) {return a - b;};

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << add(1, 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << substract(1, 2) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Still boilerplate code, but worth a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

If your primary concern is being able to "easily change the types of the parameters", it's straightforward to write them as templates so that you never have to change the types of the parameters:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto add (const T1 &a, const T2 &b) -> decltype(a + b) {
    return (a + b);
}
```

This also handles cases where `a` and `b` are not of the same type, or where `a + b` is not the same type as `a` or `b`.

Comment: I don't think OP wanted to change parameters in the first place, but operations.

Comment: He's trying to avoid boilerplate. Look at the macro example he gave.

Comment: Yes, the template required is for a binop, and 'add' is one of the arguments.

Comment: @jrok He said "I am able to easily change the types of the parameters once to change all of the functions". This is a way that he never has to change the types of the parameters.

Comment: Still completely ignores the primary question which is "I wish to create many functions with the same parameters, for example:", a bit like someone asking "I'm starving, do you have food" and responding "no, but take this plate to eat whatever you wind up with off of".

Comment: @kfsone The way I read it is "I wish to create many functions with the same parameters, but to be able to easily change the types of the parameters of all the functions I want to keep the boilerplate in one place". Thus, solving the "need to change the parameter types" problem obviates the need to avoid the boilerplate.

Answer (score 1):

If these were member functions you could declare their common type (`typedef const int Fn(int, int)`), declare the member functions inside the class using that type:

```
Fn add, subtract;
```

Then you define them outside the class in the normal way. Doesn't save boilerplate, but at least means it won't compile if you make a typo in the definitions.

Alternatively for non member functions see the question I linked to which has some clever ways to define function pointers rather than functions.